# Report C# and Sqlite how to?

Tags: c#, sqlite, report

i use sqlite in my application, but now i cant generate report in visual studio 2015, i have installed driver obdc from :

http://www.ch-werner.de/sqliteodbc/

my application works fine, insert, update, remove
i have installed from nuget package the sqlite driver

i try to use the report wizard, not sucess.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o5OuA.png)

Comment: Is it an ODBC wrapper? Maybe the data provider for ODBC could work... I create a lot of reports with C# and sqlite but I  don't use any wizard :)

Comment: how do you set the dataset ?

Comment: Hi @iwakun! About me? By code and config... When it comes to an ORM light I choose [linq2db](https://github.com/linq2db/linq2db) that works nice with sqlite and C#... but let me help you with your issues without changing your decisions :-) what's your situation? Do you actually have an ODBC interface in place for sqlite or what? Please fill your question with details

Comment: Thank You @user1892538, i just try to (load) the records to report, i have installed from nuget the linq.